# How to pass a parameter via link_to into _form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, parameters

How do I pass `challenge.name` from challenges/index into challenges/form:

**form view**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@challenge)  do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Enter Challenge' %>
  <%= button_tag(type: 'submit')  do %>
    Save
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**index view**

```
<% @challenges.each do |challenge| %>    
  <%= link_to new_challenge_path(challenge: {name: challenge.name}) do %>
    + Challenge
  <% end %>
  <%= challenge.name %>
<% end %>
```

**challenges_controller**

```
def new
  @challenge = Challenge.new
  respond_modal_with @challenge, location: root_path
end
```

With the above code if a user clicks the `link_to` I see it is passing in the server as shown below, but the `challenge.name` is not appearing in the `text_field` in place of the `placeholder` text.

**rails s**

```
Started GET "/challenges/new?challenge%5Bname%5D=HOPE+THIS+WORKS" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-02 21:52:37 -0400
Processing by ChallengesController#new as */*
  Parameters: {"challenge"=>{"name"=>"HOPE THIS WORKS"}}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 15]]
  Rendered challenges/new.html.erb within layouts/modal (8.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 11.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

Comment: you need to implement ajax ?

Comment: Can you post your `challenges/form` and controller action?

Comment: Posted form in question @PetrGazarov and updated question with controller action

Comment: I don't think `f.text_field` is a method of `simple_form`. Have you tried using  `f.input`?

Comment: Yea that didn't work @PetrGazarov, but thanks for trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `link_to` only adds the challenge name among GET `params`. You then need to pass those params to the newly constructed `@challenge` object so that simple form can use it (form works with *attributes* of the object, not GET / POST params). So, try changing the controller to something like:

```
def new
  @challenge = if params[:challenge]
    Challenge.new(params.require(:challenge).permit(:name))
  else
    Challenge.new
  end
  respond_modal_with @challenge, location: root_path
end
```

Comment: Aha, try something like the in the updated answer - you need to permit the params explicitly.

Comment: You're too quick, I just missed a parenthesis, sorry, pls retry :)

Comment: Not the first time I heard that ;)